# What is the appropriate approach to store email templates

Tags: database, database-design

Is it appropriate to store a web page in a Database? 
I am using InnoDB engine of mysql, the email templates is a modified html files that is in mail format , so there should be a plain html file.

Notice that those templates are not accessible for everyone, they should refer to the userID, so for example, User A has template1 , 2 ,3.. but UserB may have template 2,3, 5, 6..

What datatype should i store this kind of file?

Or instead of using database,  I should create a html file and use php to write in it and open a folder for each user?

Thank you for your help, I have less experience in handling this kind of data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, and for most project, the database is the bottleneck. So, if you can avoid to use it, then don't use it.
If the html is small (for example 10kb) then you can store in the database.
However, if it is big (and requires BLOB or a big varchar), then save it in a file folder using the unique id of the registry, having caution about the number of templates that could exists. However, a backup of the system requires to also backup those files (instead of a single backup of the database).

> User A has template1 , 2 ,3.. but UserB may have template 2,3, 5, 6..

It sound like

### Table User

Id_User
Name_User
...

### Table Template

Id_Template
Name_Template
Content_Template (if it is not managed by a file)
....

### Table UserxTemplate

Id_User
Id_Template

Obtain the all templates by an user

```
 select * from User a,Template b,UserxTemplate c
 where c.id_user=a.id_user and   c.id_template=b.id_template and a.id_user=xxx
```

In resume

Store in the database

Pro:

- consistence.
- easy to use

Cons:

- Performance hit
- Increase of the size of the database.

Store in a file

Pro:

- fast (only if the number of templates is not big)
- "unlimited" size.

Cons:

- Inconsistence of the data.
- Requires an extra work.
- Securities issues.

ps: Wordpress and other portal and blog system (usually) store it inside the database, however LMS (Learning Management System) stores in a file.

Comment: Thanks the template is nearly 50 kb before edit, maybe 100 kb after modified

Comment: the max size of a varchar is 64k (including the size of other columns) so i don't think that it is an option.  Anyways, you can use BLOB if you want a easy solution, considering that using BLOB impact the performance of queries that uses it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with files named as the row's primary key. It's way easier to edit, subversion, etc.

You can protect the storage folder with .htaccess `Deny from All` and use PHP's `file_exists()` just to be sure. It's <0,5ms per call, and cheaper than retrieving it as BLOB from the database.

Answer (score 0):

With SQL Server, you can store a Max of 2147483647 characters

Comment: @nalply Here is the reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx.